# How define class via Code First in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I have class Plant with some attributes.

```
public class Plant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // some attributes

    [Display(Name = "Благоприятные соседи")]
    public virtual List<Plant> PositivePlants { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Нежелательные соседи")]
    public virtual List<Plant> NegativePlants { get; set; }

    public Plant()
    {
        PositivePlants = new List<Plant>();
        NegativePlants = new List<Plant>();
    }
}
```

I hope that EF will create 3 tables in database:

```
Plants:
   Id int PK;
   // some another attributes

NegativePlants:
   Plant_Id int PK FK;
   Negative_Id int PK FK;

PositivePlants:
   Plant_Id int PK FK;
   Positive_Id int PK FK;enter code here
```

But by default I get another schema. How I can get following schema using DataAnnotation attributes or Fluent Api?

Comment: To set a DB schema in the fluent API it's `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("schema");` and in annotations it's `[Table("Plant", Schema="schema")]`. But you could have found that by searching in less time that it would take to write the question, is that really what you're after?

Comment: I have not any schema in database. I am developing my project using Code First approach. I am interesting how define my class Plant (using DA or Fluent Api) that I can get schema I wrote above.

Comment: Ah OK. I suggest you edit your question to show the schema that is generated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I overrided OnModelCreating method of DBContext in a context class like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Plant>()
            .HasMany(p => p.ReversedPositivePlants)
            .WithMany(p => p.PositivePlants)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("PositivePlants").MapLeftKey("Plant_Id").MapRightKey("Positive_Id"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Plant>()
            .HasMany(p => p.ReversedNegativePlants)
            .WithMany(p => p.NegativePlants)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("NegativePlants").MapLeftKey("Plant_Id").MapRightKey("Negative_Id"));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```